# Creating Pagination in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, pagination, dirpagination

I have a table with following data formed by response from backend . I need to give pagination dynamically and fetch first 10 records initially and when particular page is triggered need to set accordingly. I am using `dirpaginate.js` for pagination purpose. But I couldnt get the datas accordingly.

Html:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="item in searchData|orderBy:sortkey:reverse|itemsPerPage:10">
      <td class="col-sm-4">{{item[0].profileInfo.firstname}}
        <br> {{item[0].profileInfo.lastname}}
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="10" direction-links="true" boundary-links="true">
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

JS:

```
var req = {
  "request": {
    "service": {
      "servicetype": "3",
      "sort": {
        "sortby": "firstname",
        "sorttype": "asc"
      },
      "records": {
        "start_no": $scope.pagination,
      }
    }
  }
}

$scope.sortkey = '';
$scope.reverse = false;
```

Comment: How and where are you getting data from ?

Comment: I am getting data from response.

Comment: can you also show code where you have made http request ?

Comment: could you tell me what you asking exactly.

Comment: How are you getting 'searchData' value ? I can not see where the value is being set.

Comment: yes .  $scope.searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;